# Shapefile not filling properly with geom_polygon, inconsistent with QGIS/ArcMap

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal

I've imported a shapefile of the world's oceans from Natural Earth to R via readOGR. When I try to render it in ggplot, it fills in land over N. & S. America. The behaviour is inconsistent with QGIS & ArcMap, both of which render & fill the shapefile just fine. Any ideas?

```
download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_ocean.zip" , destfile="./ne_50m_ocean.zip")
system("unzip ./ne_50m_ocean.zip")
wrld <- readOGR(dsn=getwd(),layer="ne_50m_ocean")
wrld <- tidy(wrld)
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = wrld, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = "blue")
```

[screenshot of RStudio render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1iWL.png)

[screenshot of QGIS render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMP6A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using read_sf() instead of readOGR(), then tweaking the ggplot code to accommodate. Also worked for the next bit of my workflow which involved rasterizing the sf object using fasterize() for a mask ocean layer (simplified demo code included in case useful to others):

```
#get data
download.file("https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/physical/ne_50m_ocean.zip" , destfile="./ne_50m_ocean.zip")
system("unzip ./ne_50m_ocean.zip")
wrld <- read_sf(dsn=getwd(),layer="ne_50m_ocean")

#plot sf object
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=wrld, colour = "black", fill = "blue")

#rasterize sf object
r <- raster(ncol=720, nrow=360) 
extent(r) <- extent(wrld) 
rp <- fasterize(wrld, r)
ocean <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(rp))

#plot raster object
ggplot() + geom_tile(data=ocean,aes(x=x,y=y),fill="white")
```